# Prooving the inequality $\sum_{i = 1}^{k}{3k \choose 3i}{3i \choose 3}\le 2^{3k+o(k)}$ with little o

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, computer-science

I am trying to prove the following inequality:

$\sum_{i = 1}^{k}{3k \choose 3i}{3i \choose 3}\le 2^{3k+o(k)}$

I have tried opening the left side of the equation, replacing it with an upper bound that will result in an equation that I can use in Newton's Binom identity. I also tried looking for patterns of known approximation such as [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) but without any success.

Note that the $o(k)$ is a little $o$ notation: We say the $f\in o(g)$ is for every choice of a constant $c > 0$, you can find a constant a such that the inequality $0 < f(x) < c \cdot g(x)$ holds for all $x > a$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The command of Mathematica `Sum[Binomial[3*k, 3*i]*Binomial[3*i, 3], {i, 1, k}]` performs $$-\frac{1}{48} \left(16 (-1)^k-2^{3 k}\right) \left(9 k^3-9 k^2+2 k\right) .$$

Comment: @user64494 That is great! So since that is $$
\frac{3}{{16}}k^3 2^{3k} \left( {1 + ( - 1)^{k + 1} \frac{1}{{2^{3k - 4} }}} \right)\left( {1 - \frac{1}{k} + \frac{2}{{9k^2 }}} \right),
$$ my upper bound can be proved relatively easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{i = 1}^k {\binom{3k}{3i}\binom{3i}{3}} &  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^k {\binom{3k}{3i}\mathcal{O}(i^3 )}  \leq \sum\limits_{i = 1}^k {\binom{3k}{3i}\mathcal{O}(k^3 )} \\ & = \mathcal{O}(k^3 )\sum\limits_{i = 1}^k {\binom{3k}{3i}} \le \mathcal{O}(k^3 )\sum\limits_{j = 0}^{3k} {\binom{3k}{j}} \\ & = \mathcal{O}(k^3 )2^{3k}  = 2^{3k + \mathcal{O}(\log k)} =2^{3k+o(k)}.
\end{align*}
**Addendum.** Numerical calculations suggest that
$$
\sum\limits_{i = 1}^k {\binom{3k}{3i}\binom{3i}{3}} \le \frac{3}{16} \cdot k^3 \cdot 2^{3k}, 
$$
and that this upper bound is also an asymptotic approximation to the sum. The asymptotic equality in fact can be proved by using the De Moivre–Laplace theorem.